# Play a mp3 file on USB Speakers

Tags: python

I've been trying for several months to play music on my Raspberry Pi 3 or 4 with 0 luck finding a stable player for Python 3.

I can get pygame to play until it crashes which is multiple times a day so that does not seem to be a good option. This is the code that I pulled out of a larger program that plays but crashes all the time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.03125)

        self.volumeLbl.setText(str(pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()))
        if self.pyGameMusicPb.isChecked():
            path = "/home/john/Music"
            self.playMusicBtn.setText("Stop\nMusic")
            if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
                music = os.path.join(path, random.choice(os.listdir(path)))
                try:
                    pygame.mixer.music.load(music)
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                except:
                    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
                    print(f"Song {music}")
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            # pygame.mixer.music.unload()
            self.playMusicBtn.setText("Play\nMusic")

    def on_about_to_finish(self, *args):
        if self.musicList:
            filepath = os.path.join("/home/john/Music", self.musicList.pop(0))
            self.player.set_property('uri', "file://" + filepath)
            #self.player.set_property('volume', 0.1)
            self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
            #print(filename)
            (f, e) = os.path.splitext(filename)
            self.statusBar().showMessage(f"Now Playing {f}")
            #print(f"Volume {self.player.get_property('volume')}")
        else:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("No More Songs")
```

Edit: So I know the speakers work as the following works and plays the wav file.

```
john@raspberrypi:~ $ amixer
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 338
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 338 [100%] [-0.06dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 338 [100%] [-0.06dB] [on]
john@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay applause-1.wav
Playing WAVE 'applause-1.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
```

I would rather get Gst to play and this code will play on a PC just fine but no sound on the Rpi.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, os, random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
    QGridLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("GStreamer Test")
        #self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('/usr/share/pixmaps/linuxcncicon.png'))
        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        centralWidget.setLayout(grid)
        self.playBtn = QPushButton('Play')
        grid.addWidget(self.playBtn, 1,1)
        self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.playMusic)
        self.stopBtn = QPushButton('Stop')
        grid.addWidget(self.stopBtn, 2,1)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.stopMusic)

        self.exitAppBtn = QPushButton('Exit\nApp')
        grid.addWidget(self.exitAppBtn, 2,0)
        self.exitAppBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        Gst.init(None)
        self.player = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin", "player")
        self.player.connect('about-to-finish', self.on_about_to_finish)
        self.musicList = []
        bus = self.player.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.connect("message", self.on_message)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.show()

    def on_about_to_finish(self, *args):
        if self.musicList:
            filepath = os.path.join("/home/john/cajun", self.musicList.pop(0))
            self.player.set_property('uri', "file://" + filepath)
            #self.player.set_property('volume', 0.1)
            self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
            (f, e) = os.path.splitext(filepath)
            self.statusBar().showMessage(f)
            print(f"Volume {self.player.get_property('volume')}")
        else:
            self.statusBar().showMessage("No More Songs")



    def playMusic(self):
        #print('playing')
        self.musicList = os.listdir('/home/john/cajun')
        random.shuffle(self.musicList)

        filepath = os.path.join("/home/john/cajun", self.musicList.pop(0))
        self.player.set_property("uri", "file://" + filepath)
        #self.player.set_property('volume', 0.1)
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        print(f"Volume {self.player.get_property('volume')}")
        #print(self.player.get_property('current-uri'))
        filename = os.path.basename(self.player.get_property('current-uri'))
        (f, e) = os.path.splitext(filepath)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(f)

    def stopMusic(self):
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

    def setVolume(self):
        self.player.set_property('volume', 0.1)

    def on_message(self, bus, message):
        #print(message.type)
        t = message.type
        if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
            self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            #self.button.set_label("Start")
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Done')
        #if t == Gst.MessageType.DURATION_CHANGED:
        #   print('about to end')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have also spent weeks trying to find an example of PyQt5 that will play a mp3 file without any luck.

Does anyone have an example of Python 3 code that **will** play on a Raspberry Pi 3 or 4?

JT

Comment: What error does it crash with? Have you tried the omxplayer wrapper? https://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I've not tried omxplayer-wrapper. Not much information on it and it seems to be more for videos...

Comment: ALSA lib pcm.c:8424:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred

Comment: Also, malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)

Comment: also pygame the music gets distorted and you have to close the program and restart it at least once a day so clearly a very buggy program and one of the many reasons I don't want to use it.